# An anagram ..from a friend

Tags: anagram

My friend gave me this anagram.

"Chamberlains psst curs nerd!"

No clues because I don't know the answer.

A word from my friend
It would be very very very helpful

He told me 24 places including space bars

Comment: Your friend gave you the anagram - for what? Is it supposed to mean something for you or is it just *any* anagram?

Comment: There are also a lot of anagram-solver tools, have you tried any? [See here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4921/5840)

Comment: It means I cannot give extra information

Comment: I have tried them.it has two vowels,will that help?

Comment: Two? I count six!

Comment: Sorry...my friend put me off

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41478/discussion-between-john-meow-and-bmyguest).

Comment: I have to downvote this because it's just not enough to go on.  I quite like "Christmas Crabs Lend Prunes" but there are many thousands of possibilities.

Comment: There are 24 letters, so if it's really 24 characters including spaces, there can't be any spaces. There's no single-word anagram of these letters, so you get to choose from the 2.7*10^20 nonsense ways of arranging them.

Answer (score 1):

The question is clearly too broad as it stands
but if it is to be puzzle related, how about:

> Cipher unscrambles strands

Comment: Sorry..no,he says it is wrong

Comment: @JohnMeow I guess you should "down vote" your friend and explain to him, that the puzzle is bad/too broad the way it is.